# ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8 while building ionic app

Tags: cordova, admob, ionic-framework

I've been working on a Ionic project for android, I am adding admobpro plugin in my project "**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro**" it is successfully added and Added admob code in my app.js file. After that i try to build ionic app. After adding this plugin showing an error.
**ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project**.
Can any one tell why i am getting this error and solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

First step : Check if you have correct Android OS/Platform. Open Android SDK Manager and check below.

- \adt-bundle\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platforms\android-21
- \sdk\platform-tools

  - Check whether ANDROID_HOME and ANT_HOME is set correctly in
    environment Path(ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES).
    Try to get all latest.

If still it didn't fix, then try below steps. 
Install node.js
npm install grunt xxxx(if you are using grunt,then get grunt and cli.) : Node modules needs to be updated.
"npm install -g cordova"

Install Ruby from http://rubyinstaller.org/

Hope this should work for you...